# G Suite Marketplace App: detail page installation (Via User who admins multiple G Suite instances)

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace-for-business, chrome-web-store

Given that a user is the super-administrator of multiple G Suite instances; they then auth into the admin console for both of these instances.

They then navigate to the detail page for a G Suite Marketplace App, and it appears that whichever G Suite instance for which they auth'd into the admin console *first* is defaulted as the domain for which the viewed G Suite Marketplace App will be installed.

Using the supplied account picker to choose the non-defaulted account redirects the user to the relevant admin console.

Based on these observed behaviors, there does not appear to be a viable route to drive a user in the given state to install a particular G Suite Marketplace App for the non-defaulted domain. Is this accurate?